# If leave the Astral Plane do my magic items get weaker?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, planes

So the party traveled to the Astral Plane and found this old underground temple that is full of kids living in there. They have some really powerful magical weapons (they don't even know what they are for) so we made a trade with them for apple pie. I got a +5 longsword with +2d6 acid damage and a holy avenger.

Now the problem is we are going to leave the Astral Plane soon. Our cleric player said if we take the weapons with us, we'll lose some of their power, if not all, because they are not on their original plane. He is not quite sure of this rule himself though, so I am looking for rules on this.

Do weapons lose their power if they are taken off their native plane?

Answer (score 12):

**Generally, no**

If you're playing standard D&D, I don't think that restriction is in place, particularly because standard D&D tends to stay based on the Prime Material Plane and doesn't tend to bother with extraplanar matters in detail.

**However, if you're running *Planescape*, or a variant of it,** that is completely different.

The Planewalker's Handbook, pg. 110.

> More than any other type of item, magical weapons, armor, and items with bonuses (pluses) of any kind are bound to the magic of their plane of origin. Such creations are attuned to the energies of that plane, and diminish in power if they're taken from it. The further the item moves from its plane of origin, the less powerful its enchantment, at least for the duration of the separation.
>
> For each plane removed, the item subtracts one from its bonus. For example, if a battle-axe +3 forged in Sigil is taken from Sigil to Elysium, it becomes a battle-axe +2, being one plane removed. If the same axe is then taken to the Ethereal Plane, it becomes a battle-axe +0, tracing three steps from Sigil through the Astral to the Prime to the Ethereal.

Unfortunately, I don't know what setting your DM is running. Your cleric may simply be referencing this rule as he remembers it from AD&D *Planescape*. (Which proves he's not just some clueless berk!) This is understandable, as *Planescape* rules (even though they're outdated) are frequently adapted and referenced as a well-defined ruleset for the plane-traveling part of a standard D&D campaign. *Planescape* is, after all, the binding tie between all the other D&D fantasy settings and the Planes.

**EDIT:
Something to note about the rule itself and balance in the game vs. flavor of the setting**

That particular rule was not well balanced for AD&D at the time, much less later editions. Even though he is correct in remembering that this rule did exist at one time, it is probably not a good idea to houserule it back into existence for a variety of reasons. Even at the time, many of us early *Planescape* gamers houseruled that rule OUT of the *Planescape* setting because of added complexity without much added depth. To maintain the flavor, though, my group ruled that a magic item was instead *more* powerful on its plane of origin. This minimized the complexity while retaining the basic idea in the lore. Also, from a "fun" aspect, bonuses feel better than penalties.

Answer (score 3):

## By default, no

There are no rules that state magic items become less powerful based on which plane they are on. (If there were, whatever magic items you took *to* the Astral Plane would also have become weaker, right?)

Especially the Holy Avenger, which is a named item, says nothing about its power being linked to the Astral Plane.

## But still

Considering you traded one of the the most powerful swords in the world + spares for an apple pie with some kids, there's a chance these items aren't *actually* what they seem to be. However, that would be a house rule made by your DM.

They might be illusionary, or of a special enchantment that only works within the temple, or any of many things... but that's all up to your DM to decide.